# Logrotate is deleting my logs

Tags: cron, logrotate

I have this logrotate config which is **not** in /etc/logrotate.d

```
/path/to/my/logfile.log {
    su root root
    daily
    maxage 365000
    copytruncate
    dateext
    dateformat -%d.%m.%Y
}
```

I run it crontab:

```
59 23 * * * root logrotate /path/to/my/logrotate/config > /some/logfile
```

Every day I can see only two log files, the truncated logfile.log and a new logfile.log-DD-MM-YYYY file. All older logs get deleted.

Every day I copy the new rotated file and give it a new name, the next day  logs from the previous day are gone. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the following line in your configuration:

`rotate <count>`

Replace `<count>` with the number of times you'd like the log to be rotated before it removes the oldest rotated log. So five times would be:

```
/path/to/my/logfile.log {
    su root root
    daily
    maxage 365000
    copytruncate
    dateext
    dateformat -%d.%m.%Y
    rotate 5
}
```

You can check your `logrotate` man page for more information.

Comment: It works, thanks. You should fix the example though. You wrote `count 5` when it should be `rotate 5`.

Answer (score 1):

You have not used the `rotate` directive to specify how many rotations of log you want to keep i.e. how many rotations to do. If not mentioned, the default value of the parameter is `0`.

From `config.c` of `logrotate` source, check `rotateCount`:

```
int readAllConfigPaths(const char **paths)
{
    int i, result = 0;
    const char **file;
    struct logInfo defConfig = {
                .pattern = NULL,
                .files = NULL,
                .numFiles = 0,
                .oldDir = NULL,
                .criterium = ROT_SIZE,
                .threshhold = 1024 * 1024,
                .minsize = 0,
                .maxsize = 0,
                .rotateCount = 0,
                ...
                <truncated>
```

A value of `0` for `rotate` will make `logrotate` to remove old versions of the log, rather than to rotate. This is happening in your case.

So, use a sane value for the `rotate` directive to meet your need. For example, a value of `7` would do 7 rotations. If the logs are big in size, look at `compress` also.